# Read CakePHP Cookie value in JS

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cookies

There is a cookie sent in the request header on all of my CakePHP pages. Seen here:
[image: A cookie]

My problem is how do I get that value from Javascript? `document.cookie` returns `''`

Sample request header (this is the first one, send to get the page):

```
GET /pages/view_media HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.11
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Cookie: CAKEPHP=n0r405fi68i395qhaa4luse8v6
```

**EDIT**: CakePHP version is 2.4.1

Alternately, if there is a way to get the `CAKEPHP=n0r405fi68i395qhaa4luse8v6` value from the header that would work too. I just need the value.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie is being sent with the [HTTP-Only flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly), making it inaccessible for JavaScript.

## Making cookies available to JavaScript

Looks like what you are showing there is the session cookie, so you'd have to change the session configuration appropriately, specifically the `session.cookie_httponly` option:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        // ...
        'session.cookie_httponly' => false
    )
));
```

For regular cookies you would utilize the cookie components `httpOnly` option:

```
public $components = array(
    // ...
    'Cookie' => array(
        // ...
        'httpOnly' => false
    )
);
```

or property:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // ...
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = false;
}
```

## Security implications

Disabling the HTTP-Only flag should make it working, but make sure that you are aware about the security implications! Non-HTTP-Only cookies can easily be stolen via XSS, so it might be better to read the cookies in your controller and pass only those values to your view that you really need.

## See also

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#setting-ini-directives
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

Comment: Good answer. I would really question why one would want to access the session id value on client side. Chances are if you are looking to do this, there is a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Very informative. I am actually trying to get video streaming working using the html5 `<video>` tag. The problem comes when a request is sent for a seek. For some reason the `CAKEPHP=n0r405fi68i395qhaa4luse8v6` Cookie is not in the header and it gets cancelled immediately. I suspect the server is denying the request.

Comment: @dudeofea The cookie should have nothing to do with your problem as long as the video isn't served by a session bound PHP script (which I kinda doubt, though I could be wrong, just guessing here). If the problem only occurs on seeking, then your server/app probably doesn't handle range requests correctly (but again I'm just guessing).

Comment: @ndm actually it is served by a session bound PHP script. The videos are supposed to be only viewable by the users who uploaded them so it had to be under a session. I tried checking if it could handle Range requests but it won't even respond, it just cancels.

Comment: @dudeofea I see, so it doesn't have anything do with JavaScript, it's rather just that the cookie is not being sent on the following range requests?

Comment: @ndm yes exactly. This was really a smaller problem in trying to fix that. I was thinking if I could get the session id I could add it to a request header when a Range request was called but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: you've answered this question so I'll give you the karma. I've posted my follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155602/html5-video-seeking-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

```
readCookie('CAKEPHP');

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just ran this, returns null. I can still see the info about the CAKEPHP cookie in my Chrome Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that doesn't involve extra security concerns is this:

Read the cookie in your controller using your Cookie Component, assign the result to a variable and set it so you will have access to that from within the view.

```
$myVar = $this->Cookie->read('User.name');
$this->set(compact('myVar'));
```

then, in your view you will have access to $myVar.

You can even use [JsHelper::set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3aset) to Pass variables into JavaScript.